# Relation between number of features, higher order polynomial features and overfitting

Tags: regression, classification, variance, overfitting, polynomial

Recently I came across an information stating that, if we have too many features, the model is most likely to overfit. I not sure why exactly this is happening. I mean, if I don’t use any higher order polynomial equation, but use a lot of features, will the model still overfit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Modell will still overfit if you use too many features. When you use your modell with many predictors for an out-of-sample prediction (e.g. future outcomes or out-of-sample data) you will likely have an increased prediction error.

You should apply a feature selection algorithm or dimensionality reduction to select the most important features.

Comment: Please tell me how i can extend my answer if you need more detailed clarification.

Comment: did you mean feature values of test data by predictors?

Comment: Yes. Feature values of test data both by dependent as well as by independent variables.